# Wordpress table content overlapping footer

Tags: css, wordpress, footer

Hi there im having trouble with this single page on my site. The page content is in a table and crosses over the footer as you can see....

Any tips on code changes to fix this? incorrect coding somewhere throughout the tables?

Thanks heaps!

Webpage: http://www.ez007.net/FreeSamplesAustraliaByMailOnly/free-stuff-on-your-birthday-in-australia-birthday-freebies

Code from Page :

```
Everyone loves some extra love on thier birthday! Heres a list of all the epic freebie offers you can grab ONLY on your birthday each year! VERY COOL!

&nbsp;
<p style="text-align: center;">Food &amp; Dining Freebies</p>

<table class="aligncenter" style="background-color: #d6f1f4; margin: 0px auto; width: 610px; border: 2px solid #0ccff3;" border="2" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" align="center"><caption> </caption>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>

[caption id="attachment_14543" align="aligncenter" width="128"]<a href="http://club31.baskinrobbins.com.au/"><img class="size-thumbnail wp-image-14543" src="http://www.ez007.net/FreeSamplesAustraliaByMailOnly/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/SCREENSHOT-2016-09-26-11-08-128x128.jpg" alt=" BASKIN ROBBINS Free birthday scoop of Ice Cream USE - up to 14 days after your birthday" width="128" height="128" /></a> <span style="text-decoration: underline;"><span style="color: #0000ff; text-decoration: underline;"><strong><em>BASKIN ROBBINS</em></strong></span></span><br />Free birthday scoop of Ice Cream<br /><em>USE - up to 14 days after your birthday</em>[/caption]</td>
<td>

[caption id="attachment_14585" align="aligncenter" width="128"]<a href="http://www.sanchurro.com/newsletter"><img class="wp-image-14585 size-thumbnail" src="http://www.ez007.net/FreeSamplesAustraliaByMailOnly/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/121022_120993_image3_1_-128x128.jpg" alt="SAN CHURROS FREE birthday Churros For Two USE – 1 day before to 1 day after " width="128" height="128" /></a> <span style="text-decoration: underline; color: #0000ff;"><em><strong>SAN CHURROS</strong></em></span><br /> FREE birthday Churros For Two<br /> <em>USE – 1 day before to 1 day after</em>[/caption]</td>
<td>

[caption id="attachment_14584" align="aligncenter" width="128"]<a href="http://www.boostjuice.com.au/vibe"><img class="wp-image-14584 size-thumbnail" src="http://www.ez007.net/FreeSamplesAustraliaByMailOnly/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Boost_Juice_cupandfruit-128x128.jpg" alt=" BOOST JUICE A FREE Boost Juice on your birthday! USE - 2 days Before &amp; After" width="128" height="128" /></a> <em><span style="text-decoration: underline; color: #0000ff;"><strong>BOOST JUICE</strong></span></em><br /> A FREE Boost Juice on your birthday!<br /> <em>USE - 2 days Before &amp; After</em>[/caption]</td>
<td>

[caption id="attachment_14586" align="aligncenter" width="128"]<a href="https://www.subway.com.au/Eat-Fresh-Club/Login?ReturnUrl=/Eat-Fresh-Club"><img class="wp-image-14586 size-thumbnail" src="http://www.ez007.net/FreeSamplesAustraliaByMailOnly/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/subwaydeal-128x128.jpg" alt="SUBWAY Free 6-inch sub and 600mL drink USE – up to three days after" width="128" height="128" /></a> <span style="text-decoration: underline; color: #0000ff;"><em><strong>SUBWAY</strong></em></span><br /> Free 6-inch sub and 600mL drink<br /> <em>USE – up to three days after</em>[/caption]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>

[caption id="attachment_14587" align="aligncenter" width="128"]<a href="http://periperks.nandos.com.au/register"><img class="wp-image-14587 size-thumbnail" src="http://www.ez007.net/FreeSamplesAustraliaByMailOnly/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/logo-x2-128x128.png" alt="NANDOS Free regular sized Nandos meal USE – during your Birthday month" width="128" height="128" /></a> <strong><em><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><span style="color: #0000ff; text-decoration: underline;">NANDOS</span></span></em></strong><br /> Free regular sized Nandos meal<br /> <em>USE – during your Birthday month</em>[/caption]</td>
<td>

[caption id="attachment_14590" align="aligncenter" width="128"]<a href="http://www.alibaba.com.au/ultimate-rewards"><img class="wp-image-14590 size-thumbnail" src="http://www.ez007.net/FreeSamplesAustraliaByMailOnly/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Gallery_v3_01NN-128x128.jpg" alt="ALI BABA Free Kebab On Your Birthday USE – buy a kebab to get a card" width="128" height="128" /></a> <strong><em><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><span style="color: #0000ff; text-decoration: underline;">ALI BABA</span></span></em></strong><br /> Free Kebab On Your Birthday<br /> <em>USE – buy a kebab to get a card</em>[/caption]</td>
<td>

[caption id="attachment_14588" align="aligncenter" width="128"]<a href="http://www.coldrock.com.au/join-coldrock.html"><img class="wp-image-14588 size-thumbnail" src="http://www.ez007.net/FreeSamplesAustraliaByMailOnly/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/vip-freebday-128x128.jpg" alt="COLD ROCK 1 Free Ice Cream on your birthday USE – On Birthday Only" width="128" height="128" /></a> <strong><em><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><span style="color: #0000ff; text-decoration: underline;">COLD ROCK</span></span></em></strong><br /> 1 Free Ice Cream on your birthday<br /> <em>USE – On Birthday Only</em>[/caption]</td>
<td>

[caption id="attachment_14589" align="aligncenter" width="128"]<a href="http://www.muffinbreak.com.au/Muffin-Break-Club/default.aspx"><img class="wp-image-14589 size-thumbnail" src="http://www.ez007.net/FreeSamplesAustraliaByMailOnly/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Muffin-Break-Logo-292x300-128x128.gif" alt="MUFFIN BREAK A free muffin on your birthday USE – Your Birthday Month" width="128" height="128" /></a> <strong><em><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><span style="color: #0000ff; text-decoration: underline;">MUFFIN BREAK</span></span></em></strong><br /> A free muffin on your birthday<br /> <em>USE – Your Birthday Month</em>[/caption]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>

[caption id="attachment_14556" align="aligncenter" width="128"]<a href="http://gelatissimo.com.au/club-gelato/"><img class="wp-image-14556 size-thumbnail" src="http://www.ez007.net/FreeSamplesAustraliaByMailOnly/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/SCREENSHOT-2016-09-27-09-45-128x128.jpg" alt="A FREE gelato in the month of your birthday (card or app)" width="128" height="128" /></a> <span style="text-decoration: underline;"><span style="color: #0000ff; text-decoration: underline;"><em><strong>GELATISSIMO</strong></em></span></span><br /> A Free Birthday Gelato <br /> <em>USE - Must Use the month of your birthday ( rewards card or app)</em>[/caption]</td>
<td>

[caption id="attachment_14560" align="aligncenter" width="128"]<a href="https://www.cheesecake.com.au/cake-vouchers/"><img class="wp-image-14560 size-thumbnail" src="http://www.ez007.net/FreeSamplesAustraliaByMailOnly/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/g1wi35lnpxtxhqs1gcin-128x128.jpg" alt=" CHEESCAKE SHOP Birthday $5 coupon off any cake USE - Join more than 4 weeks before your birthday" width="128" height="128" /></a> <span style="text-decoration: underline; color: #0000ff;"><em><strong>CHEESCAKE SHOP</strong></em></span><br /> Birthday $5 coupon off any cake<br /> <em>USE - Join more than 4 weeks before your birthday</em>[/caption]</td>
<td>

[caption id="attachment_14557" align="aligncenter" width="128"]<a href="https://loyalty.gloriajeanscoffees.com/"><img class="wp-image-14557 size-thumbnail" src="http://www.ez007.net/FreeSamplesAustraliaByMailOnly/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/SCREENSHOT-2016-09-26-11-39-128x128.jpg" alt="screenshot-2016-09-26-11-39" width="128" height="128" /></a> <strong><em><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><span style="color: #0000ff; text-decoration: underline;">GLORIA JEANS</span> </span></em></strong><br /> Free drink on your birthday<br /> <em>USE - Must Earn your card instore with a purchase first</em>[/caption]</td>
<td>

[caption id="attachment_14558" align="aligncenter" width="128"]<a href="https://members.hardrock.com/rewards-home"><img class="wp-image-14558 size-thumbnail" src="http://www.ez007.net/FreeSamplesAustraliaByMailOnly/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/hark-rock-128x128.jpg" alt="hark-rock" width="128" height="128" /></a> <span style="text-decoration: underline;"><span style="color: #0000ff; text-decoration: underline;"><em><strong>HARD ROCK</strong></em></span></span><br /> Free dessert with any entrée purchase<br /> <em>USE - Must be redeemed During your birthday month</em>[/caption]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<div class="mceTemp"></div>

[caption id="attachment_14559" align="aligncenter" width="128"]<a href="https://secure.ikea.com/ms/en_AU/secure/family/index.html"><img class="wp-image-14559 size-thumbnail" src="http://www.ez007.net/FreeSamplesAustraliaByMailOnly/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/0135933_PE292916_S5-128x128.jpg" alt="0135933_pe292916_s5" width="128" height="128" /></a> <span style="text-decoration: underline;"><span style="color: #0000ff; text-decoration: underline;"><em><strong>IKEA</strong> </em></span></span><br /> Free Princess Cake for Ikea members <br /> <em>USE - Valid for 1 month</em>[/caption]</td>
<td>
<div class="mceTemp"></div>

[caption id="attachment_14561" align="aligncenter" width="128"]<a href="https://www.krispykreme.com.au/newsletter/"><img class="wp-image-14561 size-thumbnail" src="http://www.ez007.net/FreeSamplesAustraliaByMailOnly/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/366e38fca46ca3be7385e740e8b0d212-128x128.jpg" alt="366e38fca46ca3be7385e740e8b0d212" width="128" height="128" /></a> <span style="text-decoration: underline; color: #0000ff;"><strong><em>KRISPY KREME</em> </strong></span><br /> Free 6 Pack of Original Glazed Doughnuts<br /> <em>USE - NSW, VIC, QLD and WA <br /></em>[/caption]</td>
<td>

[caption id="attachment_14566" align="aligncenter" width="128"]<a href="http://noodlecrew.noodlebox.com.au/pages/about.asp"><img class="wp-image-14566 size-thumbnail" src="http://www.ez007.net/FreeSamplesAustraliaByMailOnly/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/NOODLEBOX-128x128.gif" alt="noodlebox" width="128" height="128" /></a> <strong><em><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><span style="color: #0000ff; text-decoration: underline;">NOODLE BOX</span> </span></em></strong><br /> $10 loaded onto your card, Valid for a Week<br /> <em>USE - collect card in-store first</em>[/caption]</td>
<td>

[caption id="attachment_14569" align="aligncenter" width="128"]<a href="http://www.redrooster.com.au/redroyalty/"><img class="wp-image-14569 size-thumbnail" src="http://www.ez007.net/FreeSamplesAustraliaByMailOnly/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/latest-128x128.png" alt="latest" width="128" height="128" /></a> <strong><em><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><span style="color: #0000ff; text-decoration: underline;">RED ROOSTER</span> </span></em></strong><br /> 1 free Meal <br /> <em>USE - Expires 30 days after birthdate, show ID</em>[/caption]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>

[caption id="attachment_14565" align="aligncenter" width="128"]<a href="https://mrsfields.customerrewards.com.au/"><img class="wp-image-14565 size-thumbnail" src="http://www.ez007.net/FreeSamplesAustraliaByMailOnly/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/mrs-fields-128x128.jpg" alt="mrs-fields" width="128" height="128" /></a> <strong><em><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><span style="color: #0000ff; text-decoration: underline;">MRS FIELDS</span> </span></em></strong><br /> Free cookie on your birthday<br /> <em>USE - collect card in-store first</em>[/caption]</td>
<td>

[caption id="attachment_14575" align="aligncenter" width="128"]<a href="https://loyalty.starbucks.com.au/"><img class="wp-image-14575 size-thumbnail" src="http://www.ez007.net/FreeSamplesAustraliaByMailOnly/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/starbucks-128x128.jpg" alt="starbucks" width="128" height="128" /></a> <strong><em><span style="text-decoration: underline; color: #0000ff;">STARBUCKS</span></em></strong><br /> Free drink on registered account <br /> <em>USE - vaild for 60 days</em>[/caption]</td>
<td>

[caption id="attachment_14564" align="aligncenter" width="128"]<a href="http://lonestarribhouse.com.au/birthday-club/"><img class="wp-image-14564 size-thumbnail" src="http://www.ez007.net/FreeSamplesAustraliaByMailOnly/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/57aacf922ca7f_lonestar-128x128.jpg" alt="LONE STAR Free meal on your birthday USE - Must purchase a 2nd meal - from $8.95" width="128" height="128" /></a> <span style="text-decoration: underline; color: #0000ff;"><strong><em>LONE STAR</em> </strong></span><br /> Free meal on your birthday <br /> <em>USE - Must purchase a 2nd meal from $9</em>[/caption]</td>
<td>

[caption id="attachment_14555" align="aligncenter" width="128"]<a href="https://chatime.customerrewards.com.au/"><img class="wp-image-14555 size-thumbnail" src="http://www.ez007.net/FreeSamplesAustraliaByMailOnly/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/chatime-freebie-aussie-128x128.png" alt="CHATIME Free drink in birthday month&lt;br? USE - membership card costs 50c " width="128" height="128" /></a> <span style="text-decoration: underline;"><span style="color: #0000ff; text-decoration: underline;"><em><strong>CHATIME</strong></em></span></span><br /> Free drink in birthday month<br /> <em>USE - membership card costs 50c</em>[/caption]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>

[caption id="attachment_14562" align="aligncenter" width="128"]<a href="http://members.jamaicablue.com.au/default.aspx"><img class="wp-image-14562 size-thumbnail" src="http://www.ez007.net/FreeSamplesAustraliaByMailOnly/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/ls-128x128.jpg" alt="JAMICIA BLUE Free slice of cake for birthday month (collect card in-store first) " width="128" height="128" /></a> <span style="text-decoration: underline;"><span style="color: #0000ff; text-decoration: underline;"><strong><em>JAMAICA BLUE</em></strong></span></span><br /> Free slice of any Jamcia Blue cake for birthday month <br /> <em>USE - collect card in-store first</em>[/caption]</td>
<td>

[caption id="attachment_14573" align="aligncenter" width="128"]<a href="http://mexclub.salsas.com.au/uprofile.py?Action=new"><img class="wp-image-14573 size-thumbnail" src="http://www.ez007.net/FreeSamplesAustraliaByMailOnly/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Salsas-Logo-e1413357992659-128x128.png" alt=" SALSAS On your Birthday Your entitled to a free burrito! USE - on Your Birthday" width="128" height="128" /></a> <span style="text-decoration: underline; color: #0000ff;"><em><strong>SALSAS</strong></em></span><br /> Enjoy a free Mex club Birthday burrito<br /> <em>USE - 2 days before or after Your Birthday date<br /> </em>[/caption]</td>
<td>

[caption id="attachment_14567" align="aligncenter" width="128"]<a href="http://www.outbackjacks.com.au/birthday-club/"><img class="wp-image-14567 size-thumbnail" src="http://www.ez007.net/FreeSamplesAustraliaByMailOnly/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Outback-Jacks-Logo-400-128x128.jpg" width="128" height="128" /></a> <strong><em><span style="text-decoration: underline; color: #0000ff;">OUTBACK JACKS</span></em></strong><br /> 3 Free Meals - When you sign up, 6 months from your birthday<br /> <em>USE - must purchase a main meal<br /></em>[/caption]</td>
<td>

[caption id="attachment_14574" align="aligncenter" width="128"]<a href="http://www.oporto.com.au/flame/"><img class="wp-image-14574 size-thumbnail" src="http://www.ez007.net/FreeSamplesAustraliaByMailOnly/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/qrhq6jddi9mqbco35ks0-1-128x128.png" alt="oporto freebie" width="128" height="128" /></a> <span style="text-decoration: underline; color: #0000ff;"><em><strong>OPORTO</strong></em></span><br /> Free single fillet Bondi Burger Value Meal <br /> <em>USE - Emailed on day of birthday, valid for 30 days.</em>[/caption]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>

[caption id="attachment_14578" align="aligncenter" width="128"]<a href="http://sumosalad.com/contact-us/sumo-society/"><img class="wp-image-14578 size-thumbnail" src="http://www.ez007.net/FreeSamplesAustraliaByMailOnly/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/sumo1979e7826-128x128.jpg" alt="sumo1979e7826" width="128" height="128" /></a> <strong><em><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><span style="color: #0000ff; text-decoration: underline;">SUMO SALAD</span></span></em></strong> <br /> Free sumo salad Valid for 7 days from birthday <br /> <em>USE - collect card in-store first</em>[/caption]</td>
<td>

[caption id="attachment_14581" align="aligncenter" width="128"]<a href="http://www.urbanburger.com.au/vip-club"><img class="wp-image-14581 size-thumbnail" src="http://www.ez007.net/FreeSamplesAustraliaByMailOnly/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/front-vip-128x128.png" alt="front-vip" width="128" height="128" /></a> <strong><em><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><span style="color: #0000ff; text-decoration: underline;">URBAN BURGER</span></span></em></strong> <br /> Buy One, Get One Free offer on any urban burger<br /> <em>USE - on your birthday</em>[/caption]</td>
<td>

[caption id="attachment_14577" align="aligncenter" width="128"]<a href="http://www.shingleinn.com/notebook/"><img class="wp-image-14577 size-thumbnail" src="http://www.ez007.net/FreeSamplesAustraliaByMailOnly/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/ls-1-128x128.jpg" alt="ls" width="128" height="128" /></a> <span style="text-decoration: underline;"><span style="color: #0000ff; text-decoration: underline;"><em><strong>SHINGLE INN</strong></em></span></span> <br /> Free Cupcake and coffee or tea at Shingle Inn<br /> <em>USE - During birthday month</em>[/caption]</td>
<td>

[caption id="attachment_14576" align="aligncenter" width="128"]<a href="https://rnrfdc.endlessrewards.com.au/register"><img class="wp-image-14576 size-thumbnail" src="http://www.ez007.net/FreeSamplesAustraliaByMailOnly/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/RIBS-AND-RUMPS-LOGO-112314-128x128.jpg" alt="ribs-and-rumps-logo-112314" width="128" height="128" /></a> <span style="text-decoration: underline; color: #0000ff;"><em><strong>RIBS &amp; RUMPS</strong></em></span> <br /> $30 gift voucher for birthday month<br /> <em>USE - get card in-store first or sign up online</em>[/caption]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>

[caption id="attachment_14579" align="aligncenter" width="128"]<a href="http://www.wokinabox.com.au/"><img class="wp-image-14579 size-thumbnail" src="http://www.ez007.net/FreeSamplesAustraliaByMailOnly/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/JMgOXEZu-128x128.png" alt="jmgoxezu" width="128" height="128" /></a> <span style="text-decoration: underline; color: #0000ff;"><em><strong>WOKINABOX</strong></em></span><br /> $12 Wok Wallet credit from 1 day before birthday<br /> <em>USE - Vaild for 7 days after your birthday<br /> </em>[/caption]</td>
<td>

[caption id="attachment_14580" align="aligncenter" width="128"]<a href="http://vapiano.com.au/our-style/fanaticos"><img class="wp-image-14580 size-thumbnail" src="http://www.ez007.net/FreeSamplesAustraliaByMailOnly/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/vapfblogo-128x128.png" alt="vapfblogo" width="128" height="128" /></a> <strong><em><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><span style="color: #0000ff; text-decoration: underline;">VAPIANO</span> </span></em></strong><br /> Free house wine/draught beer <br /> <em>USE -Birthday emails are sent one week prior to your birthday</em>[/caption]</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
&nbsp;
```

Comment: I don't know if the code is from Wordpress but it's pretty outdated. You have 142 errors in your code. https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ez007.net%2FFreeSamplesAustraliaByMailOnly%2Ffree-stuff-on-your-birthday-in-australia-birthday-freebies%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&st=1

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows both your CSS, and the HTML **output** of your WordPress page, not the WordPress code itself. You can find this by visiting `view-source:http://yoursite`, or by pressing `CTRL + U`. Cheers :)

Comment: First of all, it looks like you're loading a script (`script.js`) which uses `jQuery` but was added without `jQuery` as dependency, resulting in an error you could see by opening your browser's console. You should first fix that. And secondly, `<table>`s are meant for display of tabular data, not alignment and positioning. Your layout solution stopped being considered good practice in web design about 15 years ago. Maybe more.